# How to mix python and javascript in the server side

Tags: javascript, django

I'm creating an application that needs to pull certain data to show it to the user. This data is pulled via a JavaScript function that ideally I'd like to have on the server side, not on the source code of the page.

The flow should be:

1. User chooses 1 parameter in the website and clicks ok
2. Send a POST request to Django with that parameter
3. Django's view uses that parameter to pull another 4 parameters from the Django database
4. Somehow use this 4 parameters in the JavaScript function to get some timeseries data
5. Pass this data from JavaScript to the view, and from the view update the browser's template without the user refreshing the page

How can I pass the 4 parameters from Python to the JS function, and then the result of the JS function back to Python?

The reason I need to use JavaScript and not Python for retrieving that data is because JS has a specific library that would make my life so much easier.

Comment: I don't think this can be done on the server-side. The only option is to have that function in the template and inject parameters through Django template variables. However, I'm pretty sure that's a bad practice. Probably a better approach would be if you looked for a similar library in python.

Comment: I think you can create your js code as cli application that accepts command line arguments, and then use python subprocess package or any similar approach to communicate with your js code, but I don't think this is a good idea.